# VirtualBox on Mac OS; Archlinux as guest. How to prevent Mac OS shortcuts while using Arch in vbox?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook, virtualbox

Funny problem. I've been running VirtualBox on Windows and Linux before, this is the first time on mac. If it matters its an MBA 11.6.

How can I make Mac OS not react to all its shortcut keys while I'm inside vbox using Archlinux? This can't possibly be a feature, because its so incredibly annoying.